# Create a list of last 5 years 1. of january

Tags: powerbi

I need a list of the last 5 years of 1. of january:

```
2021-01-01
2020-01-01
2019-01-01
2018-01-01
2017-01-01

let
    Kilde = List.Dates(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()), 5, #duration(365, 0, 0, 0))
in
    #"Kilde"
```

That gives me this:

```
01-10-2021
01-10-2022
01-10-2023
30-09-2024
30-09-2025
```

I tried to do
Kilde = List.Dates(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()), -5, #duration(365, 0, 0, 0))

but I get an errro.

Any hints are most welcome.

BR Kresten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this

```
let
    end = Date.Year(Date.From (DateTime.LocalNow())),
    start=end-5,
    initial = {start..end},
    newList1 = List.Generate(
    ()=>[i = 0, j = #date(initial{i},01,01)],
    each [i]<List.Count(initial),
    each [i=[i]+1,j = #date(initial{i},01,01)],
    each [j])
in
    newList1
```

[image: Solution]